# getting a cannot read property of undefined error from vue.js when using v-model with an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to `v-model` to an array item's property. When I load the page I see `"[Vue warn]: Error in render function: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'viewFood' of undefined'` in the console and a blank page.

this is with vue.js 2.x.

https://codepen.io/jzaun/pen/YxYyJN/

html

```
<div id="ai-config">
  <div class="info">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>Resource Points</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <label>Total:</label>
      <div class="value">
        {{maxResourcePoints}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <label>Remaining:</label>
      <div class="value">
        {{maxResourcePoints - usedResourcePoints}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td v-for="(option, idx) in options">
          {{option.title}}
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="n in directions">
        <td>Direction {{n}}</td>
        <td v-for="option in options">
          <input type="checkbox", v-model="selected[n][option.key]" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
new Vue ({
  el: '#ai-config',

  data: {
    maxResourcePoints: 10,
    usedResourcePoints: 0,
    selected: [],

    directions: 8,
    options: [{
      title: 'Food',
      key: 'viewFood',
      cost: 1
    }, {
      title: 'Water',
      key: 'viewWater',
      cost: 1
    }, {
      title: 'Own',
      key: 'viewOwn',
      cost: 1
    }, {
      title: 'Other',
      key: 'viewOther',
      cost: 1
    }]
  },

  methods: {
  },

  created: function () {
    this.selected = [];
    for(i=0; i< 8; i++) {
      this.selected.push({});
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: With 8k rep you should probably avoid stating in the title that an entire framework does not work...

Comment: @marekful - fixed. With 8k rep yourself maybe you can understand sometimes people are rushed or multitasking. Sometimes not posting they best formed questions. You have the rep to make suggested edits you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two primary issues.

First, [Vue cannot detect](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) when you add a property dynamically to an object that has been added to the Vue's data. When you do this:

```
v-model="selected[n][option.key]"
```

You are adding a property to the empty object you initialized in the `create` handler. To fix that, just initialize with actual properties (or use [$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set), which doesn't appear to be an option here).

```
this.selected.push({viewFood: false, viewOwn: false, viewWater: false, viewOther: false});
```

Second (and the cause of the error you quote in your question), when you use a range `v-for` the values start at 1. So

```
v-model="selected[n][option.key]"
```

has an off by one error because as you likely know, Javascript arrays are zero based. It should be

```
v-model="selected[n - 1][option.key]"
```

There was also a minor HTML error in the original pen

```
<input type="checkbox", v-model="selected[n][option.key]" />
```

where the comma should be removed.

Here is your [pen updated](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/gxoLLV?editors=1010).

Comment: There is also a typo in HTML at line 30 of [original pen](https://codepen.io/jzaun/pen/YxYyJN/), comma is not allowed in HTML properties list (or to say, "," is not a valid attribute)

Comment: @no1xsyzy Yup, that is true; I forgot I deleted it. Thank you for reminding me!

Comment: Your code work, but you are looping on a full matrix what is not efficient as you will only process the checked elements.

Comment: @StephanePaquet It's not my code, I just fixed the question code so it works.

Answer (score -1):

I think that I have the code you need.
Check it out here https://codepen.io/spaquet/pen/MvrbLQ

I made the following change:

1. Adding value and id to all checkboxes and making sure that they are all different so you can identify which one is clicked.
2. Removed your created function. Useless as selected is defined in data (my opinion is that you may want to keep the state between relead...)
3. Added a `click` function to all the checkboxes. It is used to visualize the state of the selected at every iteration.

You can now have in selected the list of the elements that are selected with the following format direction-option.key (1-viewFood, etc.)

Answer (score -2):

`<tr v-for="n in directions">`

**directions** should be Array not Nummber

Comment: This is just wrong, and not answering the question about `v-model`. A `v-for` can take a number https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Range-v-for

Comment: ok i wrong seem range count from 1 then his last index out of range

Answer (score -2):

You initialize selected to contain a bunch of {} objects. `selected[n]` will be an empty object, so naturally `selected[n][option.key]` is null.

Changing `<input type="checkbox", v-model="selected[n][option.key]" />` to `<input type="checkbox" v-model="option.key">` works to me - it renders. All the checkboxes in a column point to the same value though - this is probably not what you want. This is because they all reference the same `v-model`

Can you explain a little more about what this is supposed to do? I can help you fix it then. Vue is great framework once you understand how it works. Maybe a mockup of what this should do or a little more explanation. Thanks.

Comment: The issue is that `option.key` isn't what I want to store info into, `selected[n][option.key]` is where  want the info. `selected[n]` should be an object, not undefined as the error is showing me. if `selected[n]` is defined then `selected[n][option.key]` should be valid.

Comment: Selected[n] is defined as an empty object in `create`, but those objects are empty - none of them have any properties. You can't dynamically allocate properties like that in Vue. Looks like the answer below solves it. Best of luck with your project!